# React Native APK not installing on Oreo

Tags: android, react-native, android-8.0-oreo

Recently I´ve created a new React Native App with the default.. basically everything. On the emulator, it works fine, but, when I try to install it on Android Oreo, it shows an "Application not Installed" message.
I´ve already generated a signed APK as I read in other posts regarding the same issue.

Maybe I should downgrade my RN Version..

Here´s my `build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
       buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I´ve had to downgrade my React Native version to 0.63 in order to make it work.